# How do I retrieve the list of products from the Google Shopping Content API v2

Tags: google-api-php-client

I have to admit to finding it impossible to find some simple code examples to give me a head start into this new Shopping Content API v2.

First task: Retrieve a list of products from the API

Ish shimple right? Probably, but I can't figure out how it all connects together.

I can create my Google_Client object, then I reckon I need to make this request...

https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2/MERCHANT_ID_WAS_HERE/products

...probably by using the Google_Service_ShoppingContent_Products_Resource listProducts() method.

Thing is, in order to instantiate Google_Service_ShoppingContent_Products_Resource, I need to pass the following arguments...

- $service
- $serviceName
- $resourceName
- $resource

...but I can't find anything to tell me what those are.

Can anyone point me at a simple example of this which works?

Comment: OK, getting a bit closer... 
`$service = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent($this->getApiClient());` 
`print_r($service->products->listProducts(self::CLIENT_ID));` gets closer. Now I just need to find the documentation on how to login first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many things the working code we ended up with was not too wordy once we'd figured out what it actually needed to be.

So we now have a class which includes these two methods which are called in the constructor...

```
private function setUpApiClient()
{
    $this->setApiClient(new Google_Client());
    $this->getApiClient()->setApplicationName(GOOGLE_API_SHOPPING_CONTENT_APP_NAME);
    $this->getApiClient()->setAssertionCredentials(
        new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
            GOOGLE_API_EMAIL,
            array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/structuredcontent'),
            file_get_contents(GOOGLE_API_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE)
        )
    );
    $this->getApiClient()->setClientId(GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID);
    $this->getApiClient()->setAccessType('offline_access');
}

private function setUpShoppingContent()
{
    $this->setShoppingContent(
        new Google_Service_ShoppingContent($this->getApiClient())
    );
}
```

Then things like this just work...

```
$result = $this->getShoppingContent()->products->listProducts(
    self::CLIENT_ID,
    array('pageToken' => $nextPageToken)
);
```

I hope this helps someone else get this running quicker than  I did!